# LU Decomposition without Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, programming, lu-decomposition

I'm creating a program to compute the LU factorization of a matrix, and I was wondering if there was a way to compute an LU factorization without using Gaussian Elimination.

I'm mainly worried about floating point errors creeping in during Gaussian elimination, as an error in computing one row would then affect all subsequent operations with that row.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I assume you're working with big matrices. If not, LU decomp is closed-form, albeit really computationally expensive

Comment: I am not an expert in numerical analysis, but I have heard of a process called preconditioning, for ill-conditionned matrices. Maybe look up those keywords.

Comment: Other methods [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Algorithms)!

Comment: Another keyword to search: "sparse matrices". IIRC they're easier to decompose?

Comment: @rhkoulen, the OP did not mention that the matrices have special structure or properties, such as being sparse. That being said, if they are known to be special, there are special methods to deal with special matrices such as sparse ones, as you mention.